# Is it possible to customize SonarQube's file details screen?

Tags: java, sonarqube, metrics, sonarqube5.1

By "file details" I mean this screen when you drill down on a file:

[image: file details example]

Here there are only the basics displayed but, for instance, if you calculate duplications, another widget will appear with duplication information.

In my case I have developed a crapload of code metrics for my language plugin; I *do* see them if I click on the link "Show all measures" (you can see it at the bottom left of the image) but I am unable to see how I can create such a widget to add to this screen without clicking on the details...

Is it possible? If yes, how do you do it?

Comment: which version of SQ do you target?

Comment: @Seb-SonarSourceTeam basically, what the stable version will be in December; I always use the latest stable version (therefore 5.1.1 at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

This "Detail" panel of a file is not customisable, and there's currently no plan to make it customisable.

When providing your own metrics, the standard "Measure Drilldown" as long as a dashboard widget should be enough to expose your information.

Comment: This is indeed what I use for the moment... However, using that measure drilldown has the problem that you have to aggregate all metrics up to the project level, and for some of them (LCOM4 for instance) aggregating them is not really useful :/

Comment: But if you don't make some kind of agreggation, then how can you guide your user to the hot points relating to your metric?

Comment: Yeah, that's true as well... To be honest, I have no idea how to aggregate in such a scenario :/ Halstead is easy, you just sum :p